# Не могу понять где ошибка. Задача найти количество простых чисел в списке. Python

Tags: python

```
l = [12, 13, 15, 32, 42, 55,17, 75, 122, 132, 150, 180, 200]
k=0
elem=l[i]
for i in range (elem):
    Pr=True
for j in range (1, int((elem)/2)-1):
    if ((elem)%j) == 0:
        Pr=False
if Pr==True:
    k+=1
    print('Простое')
else:
    k=0
    ('Не простое')
print(k)
```

Comment: Как где? В третьей строке. ))

Comment: `Pr=True` ?????

Comment: `elem=l[i]` ???

Comment: да в elem= l[i]

Comment: Почему int((elem)/2)-1, а не просто elem // 2 - 1 ?  Зачем ((elem)%j) == 0 к чему такое количество скобок, а не просто elem % j == 0 ? Что достигается последним if??? else при каждом срабатывании обнуляет счётчик простых чисел k. Какой цикл в какой вложен?

Comment: я до этого код по просто определению введеного числа явл простым или нет писал, он работает. а вот как сделать считывания со списка никак получась.  в процессе проб и ошибок выдавало что ошибка в типе данных в этой строке, int((elem)/2)-1,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ваш код. Вроде же ничего сложного, если просто внимательность включить.

```
l = [12, 13, 15, 32, 42, 55, 17, 75, 122, 132, 150, 180, 200]
k=0
for elem in l:
    Pr=True
    for j in range (2, elem//2+1):
        if ((elem)%j) == 0:
            Pr=False
            break
    if Pr==True:
        k+=1
        print(elem, '- простое')
    else:
        print(elem, '- не простое')
print('Простых чисел:', k)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Код у вас странный до такой степени...*

Перепишите лучше:

```
l = [12, 13, 15, 32, 42, 55,17, 75, 122, 132, 150, 180, 200]
k=0
for i in l:
    t=False
    for x in range(2, int(i/2)+1):
        if i%x == 0: t=True
    if not t: k+=1
print(k)
```

В  данном случае вывод `2`, что верно (простые числа 13 и 17).

Comment: я до этого решал задачу просто определения просто число или нет, а след. задание усложнилось, и я изменял тот код, чет не получись просто. С мужиками такое бывает, не часто, один разок из 5, а еще кажется что я отступы сюда не правильно вставил.

Comment: Так что, решение помогло?

Comment: да, спасибо. Буду практиковаться больше.